# Print values in table with foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i want to print out the values of `$row` in a table, i already have something but the output is not great. This is the code i have so far:

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT Titel FROM Algemeen ORDER BY Titel';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo "
        <table border='1'>
           <tr>
              <td>".$row['Titel']. "</td>"

         "</tr>
        </table>";
    }
?>
```

So the table needs to be like this with a border

- Value 1
- Value 2
- Value 3

Comment: Obviously the values will not print in the way you want , if you will put whole table inside foreach loop and print whole table again n again rather then just wrapping foreach inside `<ul>` and then inside the foreach use `<li></li>` for printing the values, simple.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look below snippet.

```
 <?php
     $sql = 'SELECT Titel FROM Algemeen ORDER BY Titel';
     ?>
     <table border='1'>
      <?php
        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row){
       ?>
         <tr>
             <td><?php echo $row['Titel'];?></td>
         </tr>
         <?php
        }
         ?>
     </table>
```

Or you can use `<ul><li>` instead of `<tr><td>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like below

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT Titel FROM Algemeen ORDER BY Titel';
echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['Titel']. "</td></tr>";    
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {?>
     <li> <?php echo $row['Titel'];?></li>
      <?php  }?>
<ul>
```